# Migrate Windows Service to WCF to monitor table and perform job processing

Tags: asp.net, windows, wcf, timer, monitoring

I've a very complex windows service, which uses Timer and scheduled every 3 secs. It triggers Elapsed event handler which inturn calls my ProcessJob() method. This ProcessJobMethod() will call BO and DO and perform the function for me.

We are planning to move this to a WCF, but i have few question on that

1) Performance is the key
2) Is there any sample which I can refer to 
3) Where should i start, what should be part of my contract and how many endpoints needed?
4) Right now there are complex structures, should it all go through DataContracts? because most functions return types are customized like JObFile..
5) What should be my adv of moving this project to WCF?
6) When WCF hosted in windows service.. who's the consumer then? I dont need or have any requirement to build console or win app. Only Windows service - should i call that as consumer

Thanks and I expect some good answers which will show me the direction to move on.